# Alternative to multithreading in Pyspark. Need to process multiple independent files

Tags: file, apache-spark, pyspark

We have to process 800 files who insert data into 800 seperate delta tables.

We used threadpool executor. Using the threadpool we call a child notebook that processes one single file.

In production the code became driver intensive and utilization of executors remained low.

After investigation we realised python multithreading was driver intensive and we were not able to leverage resources of multiple available workers.

Is there an **alternative to multithreading** we can use in pyspark that leads to more utilization of workers?

Comment: Some questions : Does all files have same schema ?, Does all files have any common column/field ?

Comment: They have different schemas. No the column names are not common.